# MySQL output with prefix using *

Tags: mysql, join, prefix

For instance we have this Query:

```
SELECT c.*, cu.* FROM cart c, customer cu WHERE cu.id = c.customerId
```

Now i will get all the data of the carts + the corresponding customer. But i would like to have that prefixed or in separate objecs as the following object.

PREFIX version:

result:

```
cartid = 384
cartstatus = 5
customerid = 443
customername = 593
```

Object version:

result:

```
cart: {
  id: 384,
  status: 5
},
customer: {
  id: 443,
  name: 593
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Generally, using * in the select clause is a messy practice and should be avoided. The solution is to use explicit column references with explicit aliases.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have "objects". How are you intending to arrive at that output?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think MySQL allows you to fetch data as "objects" as you'd like to have them. Other RDBMS know UDT's but MySQL doesn't.

If you want to have prefixes, you'll have to alias your fields one by one, i.e.

```
select c.id as cartid,
       c.status as cartstatus,
       cu.id as customerid,
       cu.name as customername
from cart c, customer cu 
where cu.id = c.customerId
```

If you frequently need those prefixes in your join query results, then I'd recommend adding them directly to your table columns, or if that's not easily possible, create views as such:

```
create view v_cart as
select id as cart_id,
       status as cart_status
from cart;

create view v_customer as
select id as customer_id,
       name as customer_name
from customer;
```

Then you can use those views easily:

```
select * from v_cart, v_customer where customer_id = cart_customer_id;
```

Comment: Txs, i was worried i had to do that... see i have to work with a existing database and need to do this for every query but thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

If I were to require a query like this, I would use a query similar to

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id AS cartid,c.*,cu.* FROM c,cu WHERE cu.id = c.customerId";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

The trick here is to create an alias for any duplicated column names such as "id" in your SQL query, so for example

```
users.id AS user_id
```

This allows us to redefine users.id so it is usable in our page as user_id when we create the variable. With my current web app I do have 2 tables with duplicated "id" columns that I have tested this solution on.

For the purpose of a demonstration to help with implementation of the working solution I am using PHP, you can ignore this if it is not relevant to you and code away in your preferred language.

The SQL output can then be used as

```
$cartid = $result['cartid'];
$customerid = $result['customerId'];
```

with the variables $cartid, $customerid and any others specified being avaliable for usage in your PHP, for example

```
<? echo $customerid.', your are currently using '.$cartid.', please make sure this is correct'; ?>
```

To help you define your variables you can do something like

```
print_r($result);
```

This will display an array like

```
Array ([id] => 1 [user_id] => 2 [shop_name] => My Shop)
```

To create the variables simply define the $result as the array ID like

```
$id = $result['id'];
$customerid = $result['user_id'];
$shopname = $result['shop_name'];
```

And so on until all the variables you need to be defined are.

Is this what you're looking for? You may need to adjust the query string as this is from memory from the last time I did something along these lines about 2 years ago.

I hope it helps.

NOTE: It started to bug me so I pulled the old code from the server, I have edited this post to correct the syntax as I previously used, the previous method I posted isn't supported by PHP however this alternative gives the desired result with minimal changes to the original query :)

Comment: Are you sure, PHP can actually access the aliased field name such as you mentioned? i.e. `c.id`? I'd be surprised if the table alias would make it to the application logic...

Comment: I tried but didnt get any output... maybe there is a step missing in the code?

Comment: I have done it before, but about 2 years ago as I mentioned... I would have to dig up the code tonight or tomorrow

Comment: You're right Lukas, I have pulled the code and corrected it to provide the desired result for the question. Thanks for pointing that out mate! :)

Comment: Where did the PHP come from? This question has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Tomalak, good question, I decided to put it up to show working code as an example of how I have implemented the SQL as a solution... it can be ignored if you don't feel it is relevant, I will leave it up to the reader, I will update the answer to reflect this. Thanks mate

Comment: Updated... SQL to answer the question is all at the top and the PHP that may be ignored showing the solution is together bleow... thanks for the tip Tomalak :)

Comment: Txs for this code, it is by far te best solution so far:) 
I am looking for a good solution for a year now so many thanks!

But i think i have to give up the perfect solution... as you stated: 'method I posted isn't supported by PHP...'

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Wasnt aiming for a PHP solution but the fact is i use PHP... so doesn't really matter:)

Comment: @Robin: Please update the question to reflect the answer that you were _actually_ looking for. Hardly seems fair otherwise. This is, of course, not "by far te[sic] best solution so far" to a question that's about MySQL.