# Mysql:Relational database , a How to?

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

I have 2 tables.

1st,cardb

**ID,car,engine,gear**

2nd,labels

***ID,label,value***

what i need to do is, say for this record

> cardb:1,punto,3500cc,auto

if i want to display this row to users, i do:

```
mysql_query(Select * from cardb WHERE ID=1);
foreach($field as $value)SELECT label FROM labels WHERE value='$value';
```

And then display the labels(user friendly version of value stored in db) to user.

**my question is**, is there a way to link the values of fields in cardb with its corresponding in labels table without having to do 2 query ??

***Example of Cardb***

- ID:car:engine:gear
- 1:Picanto:1100cc:Auto;

***Example of labels***

- label:ID:Value:label
- label:1:1100cc:'1100 Engine capacity
  (cc)';
- label:2:Manual:'Automatic transmition';

***GOAL*** seach for label of each cardb field in labels table and show it

Comment: Something is missing in your description. How to distinguish between rows in labels related to different rows in cardb? Is the ID the same as in cardb?

Comment: @Traroth , ID is not identical, to distinguish the field in cardb must be equal to labels.value

Comment: Could you give an example of a line in labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the only link between your tables is that the value field of lables contains a longer version of the text in the field label, and these shorter versions are used in the cardb, in the field car, engine and gear. And you would like a query retrieving the content of cardb, but with the long versions of the labels in car, engine and gear instead of the short that are actually in the table. The query you need is then:

```
SELECT c.ID,l1.value car,l2.value engine,l3.value gear FROM cardb c
LEFT OUTER JOIN labels l1 on c.car=l1.label
LEFT OUTER JOIN labels l2 on c.engine=l2.label
LEFT OUTER JOIN labels l3 on c.gear=l3.label;
```

Comment: Example of Cardb:1:Picanto:1100cc:Auto; Exampl of label:1:1100cc:'1100 Engine capacity (cc)';
label:2:Manual:'Automatic transmition';

Comment: So the content of labels is not directly related to the content of cardb?

Comment: the row is not linked with the other row. the link is between the Fields content of cardb which has a corrisponding = labels.value

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
mysql_query(Select * from cardb,labels WHERE cardb.ID=labels.value);
```

If you can avoid using the * and poll specific columns it is recommended.

Comment: @Ryan do i need to set any key as forign key for other ?

Comment: @Traroth this does work, it is tested, proven, valid, current and simple. Here is a [full explanation](http://www.sackoverflow.com/questions/6292106/mysql-output-with-prefix-using/6292547#6292547), I should have included this earlier, thanks for the comment mate

Comment: labels.value is not a foreign key to cardb.ID, so your query is not gonna do anything useful.

Comment: Haha... nothing useful if you call solving a problem nothing useful! It does work, I have just re-tested and verified. Check the [full explanation I posted](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6292106/mysql-output-with-prefix-using/6292547#6292547).

Comment: Just try it mate, it works for me and for a number of others that use it. Use the full explanation to generate your code depending on the database setup